# Reference to custom column in formula raises "The formula refers to a column that does not exist" (SPO365)

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, calculated-column-formula, sharepoint-list

I wanted to illustrate Calculated column in a List of a SharePoint 365 site.

My List, "Inventory", has columns "Product", "Origin" (text), "Stock (Kg)" and "Security Level" (numbers) all mandatory, with default and minimum value of zero fir the stock and security level.

I want to create a 5th column "Stock Status", calculated, as follow:

```
=IF([Stock (Kg)]<[Security Level],"Low","Ok")
```

[image: Settings>Edit Column SPO365 Page showing available fields]

Unfortunately, any attempt to make reference to any of the 4 original fields ("Product", "Origin", "Stock (Kg)", "Security Level") raises the error:

```
"Sorry, something went wrong
The formula refers to a column that does not exist.
Check the formula for spelling mistakes or change the non-existing column
to an existing column."
```

E.g.

```
=[Product]  -or-
=[Origin]   ...
```

will fail, although

```
="Hello"    -or-
=3+5        -or even-
=[Created]
```

works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the same and is working fine. Please delete the existing columns and create them without any spaces and special chars(eg:(Kg)). Internal name without any special chars. Now try to reference them.
Still if you are not able to create, then delete the existing list and recreate it.(only if you dont have data in it)

[image: Below snapshot of my trial:]

Comment: Thanks for having spent time on this. I did it again removing spaces and other special characters and it worked indeed. It actually also worked with name including spaces. However, at some point I got the issue again and
could determine that it happened under the following conditions:
(a) being in "Modern" interface and Quick Edit Mode (b) Inserting new columns. Random names were generated for fields (in my case -as on URL- "_x0061_qw4" and another time "w8c8") - I could not add these two field to any formula. Looks like a bug in the interface.